# Using a click() method is creating an endless loop

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is have my search input throughout the site display the search results on a results page that I also already have built.  This code works, but it's creating an endless loop by constantly clicking search. Is there any way I can set it to only click once? Or end the function after one click?

Thanks in advance.

```
function getParameter(paramName) {
    var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1),
        i, val, params = searchString.split("&");
    for (i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        val = params[i].split("=");
        if (val[0] == paramName) {
            return val[1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var firstRun = true;
var search = getParameter("TextBox1");
if (search != "") {
    var clickSubmit = setTimeout(function() {
        if (firstRun) {
            document.getElementsByName("TextBox1")[1].value=search;
            document.getElementsByName("btnSearch")[1].click();
            clearTimeout("firstRun");
        }
    }, 500); 
};
document.writeln('<table style="background-color: #002e58; float: right; margin-right: 140px;"><tr><td><form name="Form1" method="get" action="../zsearch.aspx" id="Form1"><tr><td style="width: 12%; font-size: small;"></td><td><input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" style="width: 233px; padding=" /><input type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Search" id="btnSearch" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12;"/></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr></tr></form></table>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're expecting `firstRun` to be your timeout ID, but it's actually `clickSubmit` in the example you posted above.

Try this?

```
var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
  if (timeoutId) {
    document.getElementsByName("TextBox1")[1].value=search;
    document.getElementsByName("btnSearch")[1].click();
  }
},500);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this option still results in an endless loop of clicking the search button.

Comment: Haha, great point Igor. No point to that. @zachariah666 could you post a Plunkr so we can see the missing context here?

Comment: It's for a contract, I cannot post it Plunkr or any similar site.  It's really just a standard form being called with click() event.  but I can't get it to stop clicking.

Comment: Hmm... you should be able to post an anonymized version of your problem... else we're just guessing. Happy to take a look if you post something more.

Answer (score 0):

The endless loop occurs because an input data is permanent. Each html page loading `firstRun` set to `true` then script submit form by trigger click event then html page loads again with same query parameters and so on.

You may break this loop if:

1. After load page you set special field, which mean "not first run" and then check presence of this field;
2. Before submit you save search field on cookie and on reload page compare cookie value and field value (if equal then "not first run").